# Expanded variables not accepted as conditions?

Tags: windows, batch-file

The goal of this code is to parse a simple text file and check if the first word of each line matches a test variable.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set testvar=pc3
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (input.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%G in ("%%a") do set pc=%%G&set vers=%%H&echo "%testvar%"&echo "!pc!"
    if "!pc!" == "testvar" (echo Yes) ELSE (echo no)
)
pause
```

In this case, input.txt is as follows:

```
pc1 ver1
pc2 ver1
pc3 ver2
```

And output is always "no"

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things.

First, `pc` and `vers` will be set to the values of each input line in turn, but the `if` test will only be done once the `for...%%G...` has finished reading each line, so it will be done *only* on the last line which is the last time that the variables will be set.

If you intend to perform the `if` test on *each* input line (you don't say...) then the test needs to be included in the `do`.

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%G in ("%%a") do (set pc=%%G&set vers=%%H&echo "%testvar%"&echo "!pc!"
if "!pc!" == "testvar" (echo Yes) ELSE (echo no)
)
```

The second problem is that the `if` test compares the *current* value in `pc` to the *literal* `testvar`. No doubt you *intendd* that it should be compared to the *contents* of `testvar`

```
if "!pc!" == "%testvar%" (echo Yes) ELSE (echo no)
```

Comment: Darn, the second one was a ridiculous mistake. Thanks for the help and clarification!